# Kohana 3.3 force SSL in controller

Tags: ssl, controller, kohana

I have a few controllers. HTTPS is redirected by the webserver (ligttpd) itself, but as a extra security-check I want PHP to redirect specific controllers to https.

Does Kohana contain a function to check if the url is running on SSL and to redirect it if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my own answer :)

Make a class called URL:

```
class URL extends Kohana_URL
{
    public static function SSL()
    {
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "") {
            $redirect = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header("Location: $redirect");
        }
    }
}
```

Call it in your controller like this:

```
URL::ssl();
```

Please note: Using only above method is unsafe. You should redirect by server (Lighttpd/Nginx/Apache) too.